# Integrating captcha with Spring Boot on Login Page

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-boot, captcha

Was looking for example of integrating captcha (any kind recaptcha, kaptcha ..) with Spring Boot on Login Page using Spring Security, using custom implementation of org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

Also how do i send additional params to userDetailsService class from Login Page ?

Thanks

Comment: Using Kaptcha with spring boot explained in this answer link: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28299434/how-do-integrate-kaptcha-in-java-spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28299434/how-do-integrate-kaptcha-in-java-spring)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do integrate kaptcha in java spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28299434/how-do-integrate-kaptcha-in-java-spring)